# How to pass only a number in a form URL

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have the code below:

```
<form action="/files/" method="get">
    <h3>GET /files/{fileId}</h3>
    <label>File ID: </label><input type="text" name="fileID" />
    <input type="submit">
    <br><br>
</form>
```

this responds with a URL: `/files/?fileID=88`

However, I want the URL to look like: `/files/88`

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so could you point me in the right direction to do so?

Comment: Read about `.htaccess`

Comment: What HTTP server are you using? express since this is tagged node.js?

Comment: it is express @Zyberzero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done from the browser, although it's not clean as you would have to use Javascript to change the form's action attribute.

```
// get hold of the form element (it needs an id)
var form = document.getElementById('form-id'),
    // get hold of the input tag (it also needs an id)
    fileIdInput = document.getElementById('file-id'),
    // get the action attribute, e.g. '/files/'
    baseAction = form.getAttribute('action');

// add an even listener to listen for the form being submitted
form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
  // get the value from the file id input
  var fileId = fileIdInput.value;

  // when it submits, change the action e.g. '/files/' + 88
  form.setAttribute('action', baseAction + fileId);

  // return true so that the form submits
  return true;
});
```

It's not really maintainable code and server side solutions to this sort of problem have been around for a while.

If you're using Express and you already have a handler for the `/files/:id` endpoint, then I would suggest using AJAX to make the request instead of a standard GET form.

For example using the [`fetch` api](http://davidwalsh.name/fetch). Fetch is a new interface for doing AJAX requests, however it's not yet implemented in all browsers. So you might want to include [a polyfill script](https://github.com/github/fetch).

```
// the first argument for fetch is the URL
fetch('/files/' + id)
  // fetch returns a promise that we can call `.then()` on.
  // our function will be called when the ajax request is done
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  })
```

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure how to implement the AJAX you posted above. Also I was thinking I could somehow just grab the value in the input which would be a fileID and store it in Javascript and then just use that in the form action? Like "form action="/files/<%=value%>". Do you think that will work? If not, could you maybe walk me through the AJAX solution a bit more as I do have a handler for /files/:fileID

Comment: The first solution does almost exactly what you are suggesting there. The only difference is there isn't a nice builtin templating syntax for doing it. However, I will comment up the code and explain the AJAX stuff a bit better.

Comment: Cool, I tried the first answer and it works fine, except for one thing. The URL is now: /files/10? and I don't want that ? there.

Comment: Ah, the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.1) says that is unavoidable. It uses that with all GET requests. Would it be possible to use a POST request instead and change the handler at the server too?

Comment: Unfortunately, it must be a GET request, but I don't think that is too big of a deal, just wanted to see if you knew of anyway to avoid it. Thank you!